# Complete redesign of a SharePoint 2010

Tags: master-page, css, theme

I'm working on a project where i need to do a complete redesign on SharePoint 2010, like changing colors, making it have a fixed size, align it to the center of the page, align the 'site action' button on the right and the welcome menu to the left, align the tabs on the right etc, but i'm having a terrible experience trying to make that happen. I achieved the simple stuff already, like defining the site's width and align it to the center of the page, but the rest..... complete fail.

I've been looking around for some references or sites where i could find more information on that kind of CSS/Master Page/Theme changes i need to make but couldn't find anything that deep on customization.

I'd appreciate if any of you could point me to a direction where i can learn a little of that kind of customization.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heather Solomon's site should be your first port of call, has everything you need to know about customising the look and feel of SharePoint.

http://www.heathersolomon.com/blog/

EDIT: this is mostly 2007, but most of the principles are the same for 2010.

Comment: Second that....

Comment: +1 excellent resource.

Comment: Thanks a lot James, i checked the blog and it helped me a whole lot..

Answer (score 2):

Check out Randy Drisgill's book; that's another great resource. http://blog.drisgill.com/